# Purpose of pressure control valve in multipoint water heater

Tags: water-heater

Most instant tankless multipoint water heater has plastic pressure valve where you can control the water pressure either in the inlet or outlet (by turning the scew below). If you make the flow weaker, does it make the water colder or hotter given the same thermostat setting)? And what if there is no pressure valve? [image]

Comment: What brand and model?    Reducing the flow on my tankless in the barn makes the water warmer or even hot if reduced enough. I use flow control to make the water warm for bathing horses.

Comment: We have an old Bosch tankless which does not have powered controls. There is a water flow regulator valve and a gas flow regulator valve.